# How to see changes in react native code with Android studio

Tags: android-studio, react-native

am new to `React Native`.  I have react native app (android). I run my app with `Android studio` and that is all working well. When I made some changes in let's say components, that changes are not reflecting in Android. I try to run `react-native run-android` but that not working?

Also I try this: `react-native start --reset-cache`

Can somebody help me with this? How can I apply code changes to the android version of my app?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you metro server is not running. Before doing `react-native run-android` try to run `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Did you apply real-time Refresh?

Enable Hot Reloading In React Native

Follow the below steps to enable Hot Reloading Feature :

First launch your app on the device or emulator.
Command To Run React Native App :

```
react-native run-android
```

Then click on emulator and press CTRL + M (CMD + M on MacOS) or shake the Android device which has the running app.

Then select the Enable Hot Reloading option from the popup.

Enable Hot Reloading In React Native